# Autofac generic type registration with interceptor and resolve it

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac, cqrs

My application contains many non-generic implementations of the generic `ICommandHandler<TRequest, TResponse>` interface. I am trying to add interceptors to them, by calling `EnableInterfaceInterceptors`. But when I try to resolve a command handler, Autofac throws an exception with the following message:

> OwnedByLifetimeScope cannot use interface interception as it provides services that are not publicly visible interfaces. Check your registration of the component to ensure you're not enabling interception and registering it as an internal/private interface type.

This is my registration and resolver code. How can i use interceptors with generic types and resolve it?

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyType.Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
    .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(LoggingInterceptor))
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(ExceptionHandlingInterceptor))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

This is resolver
```

```cs
public class CommandResolver : ICommandBus
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public CommandResolver(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    } 

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command)
    { 
        var generic = typeof(ICommandHandler<,>);
        var genericArgumentList = new Type[]
        {
            command.GetType(), typeof(TResult)
        };

        var commandHandlerType = generic.MakeGenericType(genericArgumentList);

        // Exception is thrown here
        var handler = (ICommandHandler)_lifetimeScope.Resolve(commandHandlerType);

        return (TResult)handler.Execute(command);  
    }  
}
```

**EDIT:**
i am using this interceptors on other interfaces.It works great without interceptors in CommandResolver. When i try to intercept ICommandHandler<,>, it doesnt work. I didn't write here interceptors registring code, as i said,it works on other interfaces, for example on ICommandBus. there isn't any private or internal interface, i have examined before.

Comment: I think it is a shame for you to use interceptors, because such generic `ICommandHandler<,>` abstraction makes creating and registering decorators trivial. Decorators are much easier to write and maintain and have a much better performance characteristic, compared to interceptors. For info on decorators, see: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html

Comment: Some additional info in your question may help people answer: Does it work without interceptors? Does it work with just one interceptor? Where is the code registering the interceptors? Are any of your classes or interfaces internal or private?

Comment: Also, example code may have a typo - the last line of command resolver references a "logging decorator" but that's never declared.

Comment: @Steven thanks for your comments, i know all of them, but this is not an answer, i want to use interceptors and it not works in generic types..

Comment: @TravisIllig i am using this interceptors on other interfaces.It works great without interceptors in CommandResolver.  When i try to intercept ICommandHandler<,>, it doesnt work. I didn't write here interceptors registring code, as i said,it works on other interfaces, for example on ICommandBus. there isn't any private or internal interface, i have examined before. And your last comment, you are right. When interceptors didn't work, i tried to use decorators, decorators are working great, and i have changed handler name to loggingDecorator. I missed to change it's name. i edited, thank you.

Comment: Adding the information _to the question_ is a good idea.

Comment: @TravisIllig i edited question, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you've found a bug! I've [filed an issue with the Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy repository on your behalf](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/issues/27) and I've included a trimmed down complete repro in that issue. You can subscribe there to follow along.

We can hopefully resolve that soon, however, if you have a PR with a resolution it'll likely be much faster.

Sorry that's not the answer you were probably hoping for, but at least it's an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way, i changed my interceptors to decorators :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is actually the fact that `AsClosedTypesOf()` registers a service as both the concrete class and the closed interface - as they are both closed types of the provided interface.

As long as you are only ever resolving via the interface you can solve this issue by modifying the `AsClosedTypesOf()`  extension method to only register interface types.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that a type from a scanned assembly is registered if it implements an interface
        /// that closes the provided open generic interface type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TLimit">Registration limit type.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TScanningActivatorData">Activator data type.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TRegistrationStyle">Registration style.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="registration">Registration to set service mapping on.</param>
        /// <param name="openGenericServiceType">The open generic interface or base class type for which implementations will be found.</param>
        /// <returns>Registration builder allowing the registration to be configured.</returns>
        public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TScanningActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle> AsClosedInterfacesOf<TLimit, TScanningActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TScanningActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle> registration, Type openGenericServiceType) where TScanningActivatorData : ScanningActivatorData
        {
            if ((object)openGenericServiceType == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(openGenericServiceType));
            if (!openGenericServiceType.IsInterface)
                throw new ArgumentException("Generic type must be an interface", nameof(openGenericServiceType));

            return registration
                .Where(candidateType => candidateType.IsClosedTypeOf(openGenericServiceType))
                .As(candidateType =>
                    candidateType.GetInterfaces()
                        .Where(i => i.IsClosedTypeOf(openGenericServiceType))
                        .Select(t => (Service)new TypedService(t)));
        }
```

And then you can change your registration to

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyType.Assembly)
    .AsClosedInterfacesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
    .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(LoggingInterceptor))
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(ExceptionHandlingInterceptor))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Very nice solution, you saved me allot of work.  Thx!